# Boost Fusion invoke and SFINAE

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, invoke, sfinae, boost-fusion

I would like to achieve partial class template specialization based on whether `boost::fusion::invoke()` with a particular Fusion sequence would work or not.  But it seems that substitution failure in this case IS an error.

I guess I need an `is_callable_with_these_sequence_parameters<F, Seq>` metafunction that works.  Can anyone help?

```
struct F
{
    template<class> struct result;
    template<class F> struct result<F(float)> { typedef int type; };
    int operator()(float) { std::cout << "invoked (float)\n"; }
};

template <class Sequence, class Enable=void>
struct A
{
    A() { std::cout << "invoked nothing\n"; }
};

// Partial specialization
template <class Sequence>
struct A<Sequence, typename boost::fusion::result_of::invoke<F, Sequence>::type>
{
    A() { boost::fusion::invoke(F(), Sequence()); }
};

static void test()
{
    A<boost::fusion::vector<float> >(); // should print "invoked (float)"
    A<boost::fusion::vector<char, char> >(); // should print "invoked nothing"
}
```

Comment: Uhh. I think I understood the code, but can't see what's wrong with it. What *should* it print? Could you clarify?

Comment: It does not compile as-is on MSVC 2010.  Partial specialization does not seem to work as I had hoped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some investigation I think that this is a bug in boost.

Reported [here](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6915), no workarounds so far.

---

**Update:** some incorrect behavior of `boost::fusion` has been fixed, according to the ticket.

Comment: Many thanks for your help!  I'll watch the issue and in the meantime try a different approach.